# Why span aligned beyond the bottom and how may I manipulate it

Tags: html, css

Please, explain me **WHY** this is happening - why the text of the span is aligned **beyond** the bottom of the image - and how may I actually manipulate the span to move it in x and y coordinates, because manipulating it with `padding` and `margin` doesn't work on it. I can make it work eventually, but there must be some simple way of doing this.

HTML:

```
<div class="cnt">
  <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41jlGA2RzmL._SS40_.jpg"><span>zzz</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body,.cnt,img,span {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.cnt {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
}
.cnt img {
  background: #090;
}
.cnt span {
  margin-top:-20px;
  background: #333;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kcepLrhx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `vertical-align` of an `img` is to align at the baseline. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

To change it, change `vertical-align` on the `img`

```css
html,body,.cnt,img,span {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.cnt {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
}
.cnt img {
  background: #090;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.cnt span {
  margin-top:-20px;
  background: #333;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="cnt">
  <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41jlGA2RzmL._SS40_.jpg"><span>zzz</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks once again, Michael! :) Just to add to your answer: to manipulate the `span` in case like this, it's possible to use `px` or `%` value of the `vertical-align`. for example: `span { vertical-align: -20px;}`

Answer (score 0):

You can actually set the `span` position to absolute, then you'll have the control over the x and y coordinates with the margin propiety. Make sure that `cnt`'s position is **relative**, which is the default position of any element you create.

For example:

```css
html,body,.cnt,img,span {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.cnt {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  position: relative; /* It is the default value */
}
.cnt img {
  background: #090;
}
.cnt span {
  background: #333;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  position: absolute; /* span position is absolute to the div position */
}
```

```html
<div class="cnt">
  <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41jlGA2RzmL._SS40_.jpg"><span>zzz</span>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lgyw4co2/